# TextIO.getln() does not get input?

Tags: java

I'm newbie in Java. I'm reading the book Introduction to Programming Using Java v7 and found problem with code like this:

```
public class CreateProfile {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name;
        String email;
        double salary;
        String favColor;

        TextIO.putln("Good Afternoon! This program will create");
        TextIO.putln("your profile file, if you will just answer");
        TextIO.putln("a few simple questions.");
        TextIO.putln();

        /* Gather responses from the users. */


        TextIO.put("What is your name?      ");
        name = TextIO.getln();
        TextIO.put("What is your email address?      ");
        email = TextIO.getln();
        TextIO.put("what is your salary income?      ");
        salary = TextIO.getDouble();
        TextIO.putln();
        TextIO.put("What is your favorite color?     ");
        favColor = TextIO.getln();

        /* Write the user's information to the file named profile.txt. */

        TextIO.writeFile("profile.txt"); //subsequent output goes to file
        TextIO.putln("Name:     " + name);
        TextIO.putln("Email:    " + email);
        TextIO.putln("Favorite Color:    " + favColor);
        TextIO.putf("Yearly Income:      %1.2f%n", salary);

        /* Print a final message to standard output. */

        TextIO.writeStandardOutput();
        TextIO.putln("Thank you. Your profile has been written to profile.txt.");

   }
}
```

The console does not ask me to input the **favorite color** but jump directly to writing file process.

[image]

As when I put the favColor input statement before the salary, there seem to be no problem:
 [image]

Can anyone please explain me why?

Comment: You are misusing javers tag, please remove it (leave only java)

Comment: Hi, What is a javers tag? I believe that I have used only Java with TextIO class?

Comment: Ah OK I think I know what are you talking about. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my program. I figured out the problem by remember something about registers I was taught.

in your code the problem is this section:

```
salary = TextIO.getDouble();
TextIO.putln();
TextIO.put("What is your favorite color?     ");
favColor = TextIO.getln();
```

When you called textio.getdouble() the program just takes the number entered and leaves the end of file symbol to be retrieved with the next GET statement. So in your code when you called textio.getln() it retrieved end of file and saved nothing because getln only takes the input from before the end of file character.

SOLUTION:
put a line after getdouble  like this

```
salary = TextIO.getDouble();
TextIO.getln();
TextIO.put("What is your favorite color?     ");
favColor = TextIO.getln();
```

I tested it and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `TextIO.putln();`

```
TextIO.put("What is your name?      ");
name = TextIO.getln();
TextIO.put("What is your email address?      ");
email = TextIO.getln();
TextIO.put("what is your salary income?      ");
salary = TextIO.getDouble();
//TextIO.putln();
TextIO.put("What is your favorite color?     ");
favColor = TextIO.getln();
```

Regards.

Comment: Hi, I try to remove it but the problem is still there.